# ImportError: cannot import name 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I tried to use  django-endless-pagination
https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html#quickstart
And I follow tutorial

I wrote:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

And got this error:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
ImportError: cannot import name 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'
```

What do I do?

Comment: What is your version of Dajngo?

Answer (score 1):

The docs of endless pagination are not updated. `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` was deprecated as of Django 1.8 and removed in 1.10. Please refer to upgrade  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/, it shows where to place context processors.

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions are written for Django 1.7 or earlier.

They have not been updated for the new `TEMPLATES` setting in Django 1.8, and will not work in Django 1.10+.

For this particular part of the instructions, removing those lines from your `settings.py` should be enough, because the `request` template context processor is enabled by default in Django 1.8+.

However, it looks as if django-endless-pagination [is no longer supported](https://github.com/frankban/django-endless-pagination/issues/92) so you might have other problems using it with recent versions of Django. You could try [this fork](https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination) instead.